# How to accept a double quote value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a very interesting scenario How can accept value like this in jquery

```
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

Right now jquery only accept value till first double quote

```
System.out.println(
```

I am getting this value using

```
var useranswer = $("input[name='radgroup1;?>']:checked").val();
```

```
<input type="radio" name="radgroup1>"
value="System.out.println("Hello world")">System.out.println("Hello world")</label>
```

Thanks for your help fairly new to jquery

Comment: what will be the values for $question->id ?

Comment: it is a number like 1, 2, 3 and so on for every question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample code for your requirement, Please check If it helps you?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input name="radgroup1" type="checkbox" value='System.out.println("Hello world")' checked="checked" />
<input name="radgroup2" type="checkbox" value="22"  />
<?php $question = 1; ?>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    var useranswer = $("input[name='radgroup<?php echo  $question;?>']:checked").val();
    alert(useranswer);
});
</script>
```

Feel free to know your doubts

Comment: Doesn't help your answer doesn't even fit the context

Comment: @RohitJain Can you update your question to add your input checkbox samples ?

Comment: No, It clearly say i want to accept var string = System.out.println("Hello world");

Comment: Where this var string = System.out.println("Hello world");  comes in the contest ?

Comment: It is from a database

Comment: Still not clear brother, Can you tell me where this System.out.println comes in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203510/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-ajith).

Answer (score 1):

> try this:

```
use console.log(useranswer);
```

> and press f12 key to view your answer